# How do i make zoom in zoom out with the mouse wheel over a drawn rectangle area?

Tags: c#, winforms

This the code im using to draw a rectangle over a pictureBox1:

```
private void DrawRectangle(Graphics e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
    {
        e.DrawRectangle(pen, mRect);
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mRect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}


private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        mRect = new Rectangle(mRect.Left, mRect.Top, e.X - mRect.Left, e.Y - mRect.Top);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

How do i make that after i drawed a rectangle when i move the mouse wheel up or down it will  resize the drawn rectangle area on the iamge in the pictureBox1 ?
Not resize all the image but make zoom in/out only for the rectangle drawn area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get familiar with the MouseWheel event.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse wheel events can be manually added as shown below, of course you can set it up as you need:

```
this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseWheel);

private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    e.Delta;
    // e.Delta: Represents the amount the wheel has changed. This value is positive if the mouse wheel is 
    // rotated in an upward direction (away from the user) or negative if the mouse wheel
    // is rotated in a downward direction (toward the user).
}
```

You can use the `Graphics` class' `ScaleTransform` to scale your drawn rectangle.